# Pandas: Reverse operation of "split string to separate rows"

Tags: python, pandas

Below code explains how to split string to separate rows for a pandas DataFrame

```
df_A=pd.DataFrame({'ABC':['A','B','C'],'XY':['x,y','x,y','y']})
df_A
Out[159]: 
  ABC   XY
0   A  x,y
1   B  x,y
2   C    y

df_xy = df_A['XY'].str.split(',',expand=True).stack().str.strip().reset_index(level=1,drop=True)
df_xy = pd.DataFrame(df_xy,columns=['XY'])
df_B = df_xy.join(df_A.drop(['XY'],axis=1)).reset_index(drop=True)

df_B
Out[161]: 
  XY ABC
0  x   A
1  y   A
2  x   B
3  y   B
4  y   C
```

What I have to do is exactly opposite, I have `df_B` as my input and my output should be `df_A`

Comment: Use `df.groupby('ABC')['XY'].agg(','.join).reset_index()`